# richfaces a4j:support event unexpected calling backend methods

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf, richfaces-modal

I work on a JSF 1.2 application with Richfaces 3.3. I have a popup which contains a `rich:extendedDataTable`. When I click a row in a table I want to enable or disable a button, and I use `a4j:support event="onRowClick"`.

Here is some code:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:panel id="main">
        <a4j:commandButton id="completed" value="Completed" 
        rendered="#{bean.completedCase}" />

        <a4j:commandButton  value="Open"
                oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupId')}.show(...)">
        </a4j:commandButton>

        <rich:modalPanel id="popupId">
            <a4j:region>

                <rich:extendedDataTable id="source" value="#{bean.sourceItems}" 
                    var="sourceItem" selectionMode="single" >
                    <a4j:support event="onRowClick" eventsQueue="pickQueue" reRender="copy" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{sourceItem}"
                            target="#{bean.sourceSelection}" />
                    </a4j:support>
                    ....
                </rich:extendedDataTable>           

                <a4j:commandButton id="copy" value="Copy" />
            </a4j:region>

            <a4j:commandButton value="Ok" reRender="completed"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupId')}.hide();return false;">
            </a4j:commandButton>

        </rich:modalPanel>
    </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

The problem is that when I click a row, then in the backend are called some methods that are use to render a button: `rendered="#{bean.completedCase}"`, but the button is not on the popup, but on the page beyond the popup. Any idea why there are called other methods than the ones used for the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ajaxsingle="true"` on your `a4j:support` tag. Since your are using `h:form` when the onrowclick fire a request ,all of the components inside the h:form will be processed on the server during update model phase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ajaxSingle="true" does not help me because I want some other components to be processed.

Comment: you can use the process attributes in your a4j:support tag, then list all the components you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

Its not advisable to have nested `<h:form>`s but we can have multiple `<h:form>`s ,try
modifying your code in such a way that the `<h:commandButton>` are in one `h:form` and the `<h:modalPanel>` is in another form

Hope this helps. u can also give a try with `<a4j:form>` for `modalPanel`